# PostgreSQL Python copy table from one database to another

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2 in Python to manage 2 databases. I want to copy data from every table in db1 into db2. I don't want to use pg_dump because I want to be able to update the tables in the second database as changes are made to the first and pg_dump won't run if data in the table already exists. As of now, I have 2 cursors for each database. I'm copying tables using

`result = cursor1.execute('SELECT * from "table1"')`

I'm trying to do something like

`cursor2.execute('INSERT INTO table2 result')`

I've also used pg_dump -s to replicate the same schema of the first database in the second.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3):

If you iterate over the result and for every row use insert statement would work but might not be the right way to do this transfer(updated like @Jules says):

```
for row in result.fetchall():
    cursor2.execute('INSERT INTO table2 VALUES %s',(row,))
```

Comment: Just a nitpick -- `'string'%variable`-style formatting is generally deprecated in Python. `dbapiv2`-compliant modules support a tuple-based syntax: `cur.execute('INSERT INTO table2 %s', (row,))` (where the trailing comma in the tuple is intentional).

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Jules Apparently there are some foreign keys linked to other tables, which prevents me from directly inserting into this single table. Is there a way to insert into all linked tables?

Comment: I'm getting the error "insert or update on table "BeverageMenuMap" violates foreign key constraint "FK_BeverageMenuMap_Beverages_BeverageId"

Comment: @ArushShah you would have to share the foreign key constraints on that table. This may be more suitable for another question or possibly chat, although I'd recommend that you look up the principles of working with FK constraints in Postgres.

Comment: This is quick way to do. Thank you @metmirr